# How to implement Event bus types suggestion in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-bus

Hello I am facing problem when trying to implement types for [TinyEmitter](https://github.com/scottcorgan/tiny-emitter). I need to implement 2 methods.
First:

```
addEventListener(e: string, (...args: any[]) => void): void;
```

Second:

```
emit(e: string, ...args: any[]): void;
```

But this solution is not suggesting event names, and parameters.

I need to define event types, and event arguments.
Something like:

```
type EventMap = [
 (e: 'event1', arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: string) => void,
 (e: 'event2', arg1: string, arg2: string) => void,
 ...
];
```

Actually i can infer event name by:

```
type EventParam<I extends number = number> = Parameters<EventMap[I]>[0];
```

this will infer event type `('event1' | 'event2')`
For other parameters i tried:

```
type EventArgs<I extends number = number> = EventMap[I] extends ((e: EventParam<I>, ...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

how to implement this for `addEventListener` and `emit` functions with type suggestions ?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wj0jvm) meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining (although probably not explaining the implementation of the `makeFoo()` function, just the typings for it). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Related: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-emitter and https://www.npmjs.com/package/emittery

Comment: If i little edit [EventArgs](https://tsplay.dev/wOl9EN) to named args, in TS playground i can see clear suggestion for addEventListener,
`addEventListener(e: "event1", cb: (arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: string) => void): void`, but in PHPStorm i see just `cb: (...args: EventArgs[string]) => void`.
Any idea how to resolve this ? Maybe problem with parsing in TS plugin ?

Comment: @Dimava typed-emitter is working. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what to say about your particular IDE; is the question specific to PHPStorm?  Please let me know if I should write an answer (because you're likely to accept it) or disengage (because you're not likely to accept it due to IDE issues or going with some library as suggested by the other commenter)

Comment: @jcalz Hello, i edit your implementation to [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3B92N), i need to implement emitter on object. So use abstract class is best approach for me. What do you think about this implementation ?

Comment: I think it's probably fine but that's outside the scope of the question as asked (and changing the question now to expand the scope would be inappropriate here).  I'm still waiting for a yes or no to my previous question.  If I write up my suggestion as an answer, would that fully address the question *as asked* and you'd be likely to accept it?  Please give me a clear "yes" or "no" so I can proceed.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz Yes, you can.

Comment: Okay I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I'd recommend is to make a utility interface which maps the name of the event (as a key) to the corresponding list of argument types (as a value):

```
interface EventArgs {
    event1: [number, string, string];
    event2: [string, string];
    // ...
}
```

Then you can define your `addEventListener()` and `emit()` methods as being [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the type of the `e` argument [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be a key of `EventArgs`:

```
interface Foo {
    addEventListener<K extends keyof EventArgs>(e: K, cb: (...args: EventArgs[K]) => void): void;
    emit<K extends keyof EventArgs>(e: K, ...args: EventArgs[K]): void;
}
```

I'm calling the interface `Foo` since it wasn't specified in the question.  Then assuming we have an implementation that makes a `Foo`:

```
const foo: Foo = makeFoo();
```

We can see that it behaves as desired:

```
// Good calls
foo.addEventListener("event1", (n, s1, s2) => {
    console.log(n.toFixed(2), s1.toUpperCase(), s2.toLowerCase()); // okay
});
foo.emit("event2", "Abc", "Def"); // okay
foo.emit("event1", Math.PI, "Abc", "Def"); // okay

// Bad calls
foo.emit("event1", "Abc", "Def"); // error! 
foo.addEventListener("event2", (n, s1, s2) => { // error! 
    console.log(n.toFixed(2), s1.toUpperCase(), s2.toLowerCase())
});
```

---

That essentially answers the question which is primarily about typings; still, it can be implemented like this in a fairly type-safe way:

```
function makeFoo(): Foo {
    const listenerMap: { [K in keyof EventArgs]?: ((...args: EventArgs[K]) => void)[] } = {}
    const ret: Foo = {
        addEventListener<K extends keyof EventArgs>(e: K, cb: (...args: EventArgs[K]) => void) {
            const listeners: ((...args: EventArgs[K]) => void)[] = listenerMap[e] ??= [];
            listeners.push(cb);
        },
        emit<K extends keyof EventArgs>(e: K, ...a: EventArgs[K]) {
            const listeners: ((...args: EventArgs[K]) => void)[] = listenerMap[e] ?? [];
            listeners.forEach(cb => cb(...a))
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Essentially it just holds onto an object map from event names to arrays of event listeners, and `addEventListener` pushes the listener onto the right array (initializing it first if need be), while `emit` calls the listeners from the right array (unless it doesn't exist).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgIJQOYDOyA3gFDIXISbgCMAXMgNogCuAtgEbQA0yBYKKDx8BQkHgC6AbnKVqWMACZGTMcNGDhMuRQD0e5ADoTpAL6lSoSLEQoAYgHtHJXcjgATDxkUAZYAJY0AA8ANJUAB6QIB5EANYQAJ6OMGg0YLiEAHwAFBCMoXwInIw5JkZw+ASMPjhVTKGSAJTIALxZyOiOwB5NjF09spRU7MBgYZHRscgJyam1GVW5+ciFxiaVhDXpmQQNzf3dHrIWCI4gAsgwzm3I7HAJTo45TbLXjhVeC-6BINA5ACIFHQAXwciBRLRREoWu1XMMzhdHAAbCBGZGOPDgoxgRz2YARCAeHIwyE4xwAVQADlToABhOAECAvaHk3yOADu9MZzKaTXMr1I7yMEFGYEBwOUoOQAOwnAQ0oBABEIDAAa9kAZkCBHGAABbCZB6uA0rAEIXOEViiXpWjSgCycH1RgACgBJPiy+WKlVqjVagEAZiMtAALIrsAAhOmKjyqgGWQSJeGUYWisY2xR2z1yhWe33q6SawzQKCOKAAQmQbmFnm86R+0X+QPSSml4Mh0NhHWIxaoUDLlerwwR5wIKLRGKxIHJ+MJxNJ-Fo5OptKgDKZLP4SjZnO5m75bjMgrMyAQToQeuQeRaZFHSNR6MxN-MliFrBACDAwHOdweECeF5GCeFMKERS5kQCJsoEdKlGF7BpkFAGYkhSNJFF2SQAH5SjKDYqm2DD6kabtOiOJomEkZBT1aEgLHvS4oAgMBgJuWi7xHCg62+KCgigCYICiLBplmNCFl2ZYCiKEpr3KTZqnQupCH2UiBl6UDOMocCwGQSDfmgBScjwioCMUxZlJItoOjUiiqNovToNgpgICorCsNoyihk04YHL4ggjCpVgCD1HJikFbyzB4NxhnTcZwkEqZ4lQ+YdiWPIpPWCpCKUvZLI47ywLHHTfL+KBDOM+TsvM3Lmissiels24SugJyXOQNzmB0ArKGasqjGuKBUEQELijq4oKsPCKjzcJiwFYKAQGQWaTlIIA)